# Python, panda replace value using loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I don't understendt why this dose not work.
I want to find all empty cells and write in it column name add 100.
For exlample 'OrgName100'

```
columns =['OrgName','IdCode','CategoryMain']
for columnName in columns: 
       df.loc[df[columnName] == ' ', [columnName]] = columnName + '100'
```

Comment: Is it possible its only '' and not ' '?

Comment: A cell with a whitespace is not an empty cell but a cell with one character.

Comment: df.loc[df[columnName] == "", [columnName]] = columnName + "100". it dose not work.

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn  Can you tell me wright code?

Comment: @GeorgeKatsadze I would be happy to work with you, I would just need to know what comes across as a blank field in your data, which can be hard to do sometimes. Could you provide a sample set of data? At least that way we could show you an idea of what you can do

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn. I have several companies financial data, which has empty cell i want to fill this cell with certain criteria to make financial information useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your ' ' strings by `nan` then use `fillna`:

```
columns = ['OrgName', 'IdCode', 'CategoryMain']
mapping = {c: f'{c}100' for c in columns}
df[columns] = df[columns].replace(' ', np.nan).fillna(mapping)
```

**Update**

> Instead of 100 can I add one columns certain row value. For example in OrgName in row5 is written "134", I want in Idcode row5 (in empty cell) to write Idcode134?

```
df1 = (pd.DataFrame([df.columns], columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
           + df['OrgName'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
df[columns] = df[columns].replace(' ', np.nan).fillna(df1)
print(df)

# Output
  OrgName   IdCode CategoryMain
0       x        1            f
1       y        2            d
2       z  IdCodez            g
```

Comment: Thanks. One more question instead of 100 can I add one columns certain row value. For example in OrgName in row5 is written "134", I want in Idcode row5 (in empty cell) to write Idcode134?

Comment: You always get the value from `OrgName` column?

Comment: Yes get values from only OrgName column. but rows are different, but same for other column.

Comment: I have data frame ['OrgName','IdCode','CategoryMain']  {'OrgName': [x,y,z],'IdCode': [1,2,nan], 'CategoryMain': [f,d,g]}. Idcode has 3thrd empty cell and instead of this value there must be written "IdCodez'. To concatenate OrgNames 3thrd cell value to Idcode column name. Thank you.

Comment: Does it mean there is always a value in `OrgName` columns?

Comment: Yes OrgName is always has value